# Time Series Plot group by date in R

Tags: r

I have got the following data frame:

```
Tweets_text    date            Hashtag1     Hashtage2
xxxxxxxxxx     2021-01-01          1            0
xxxxxxxxxx     2021-01-01          1            1
xxxxxxxxxx     2021-01-02          0            1
```

And I want to create a plot that shows how many tweets were associated with each hashtag on each day. I've tried lots of methods but none of them work.

Answer (score 0):

If using `ggplot2`, then it is easiest to put it into long format first, and we can go ahead and summarize the data as well to make it easier to plot.

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
  pivot_longer(-c(Tweets_text, date)) %>% 
  group_by(date, name) %>% 
  summarize(value = sum(value)) %>% 
  ggplot() +
  geom_line(aes(x = date, y = value, color = name, group = name))
```

**Output**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
  pivot_longer(
    starts_with("Hash")
  ) %>% 
  group_by(date) %>% 
  summarise(sum = sum(value)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = date, y=sum, group=1)) +
  geom_point()+
  geom_line()+
  expand_limits(x = 0, y = 0)+
  theme_classic()
```

[image]